# Static exception instance

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

Are static exception instances safe to use? Any good reason to avoid the following?

```
public class ResourceHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private static HttpException notFoundException =
                new HttpException(
                    (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
                    "Assembly Not Found");

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        ....
        throw notFoundException;
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An exception's stacktrace is set when it is thrown (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx), so this code is not thread safe.

Multiple threads will be using the same exception object and anyone relying on the content of the exception will get confusing results.

Comment: Thanks, I was sure there was something wrong, I just couldn't find out what :)